# Does TableQuery support OrderBy?

Tags: c#, azure, odata, azure-storage

I can't figure out how to add a [OrderBy](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#orderby) clause to a [TableQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery_members.aspx) with [Azure Table Storage](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/).

According to [their documentation Azure supports OData $orderby](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg312156.aspx). If I try to hack it by adding `$orderby=PartitionKey` to the [TableQuery Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery.where.aspx) clause the `'$'` is HTTP-encoded and I get a 400 server error because of it - so hacking it in wont work. Here is what my hack produces:

```
GET /devstoreaccount1/NewTable3?$filter=PartitionKey%20ne%20%27pkey992%27%24orderby%3DName&$select=Name%2Cregistered%2CPartitionKey%2CRowKey%2CTimestamp HTTP/1.1
```

Does [TableQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablequery_members.aspx) support [OrderBy](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#orderby), and if yes then how?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Does TableQuery support OrderBy, and if yes then how?`

No. As of today, `Table Service` does not support `Order By`. Please see the list of supported `LINQ Operators` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/storageservices/query-operators-supported-for-the-table-service).

What you would need to do is fetch the data (which will be sorted by PartitionKey and RowKey) and apply the sorting on the client side.

Comment: Yes, I found this list of supported OData query options for the Azure Table Service now and $orderby is not on it, shame. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894031.aspx

Comment: Yes, another API half done by Microsoft :(